# D-Product (Absolute U AND V)

Tags: vectors

Can someone explain for solution b why absolute u is 2 and absolute v is 1. I am a little confused with d-product examples.

[image: D-PRODUCT EXAMPLE]

Comment: I edited and added my picture.

Answer (score 0):

for part (b), you have $\vec{u} = \left(\sqrt3,1\right)$ and $\vec{v} = (0,1)$. You have
$$
\left\| \vec{u} \right\|^2 = \vec{u} \cdot \vec{u} = \left(\sqrt3\right)^2 + 1^2 = 4
$$
which means $\left\| \vec{u} \right\| = \sqrt{4} = 2$.

Can you do the other one yourself?

Comment: How come we squared the u are we supposed to square both u and v when calculating totals?

Comment: @OGK not sure what you are asking. To find $\left\| \vec{v} \right\|$ you can follow the same approach, take the square root of the squares of individual coordinates. The reason I showed you how to compute the square of the size first is because it is easier to compute.

Comment: I understand, I have another question how did they know the angle was pi/3?

Comment: @OGK it's easy to see if you draw the picture. Note $\vec{v}$ is along the $y$-axis in the plane, and $\vec{u}$ crosses the unit circle at $$\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}, \frac12 \right) = \left( \cos \frac{\pi}{6}, \sin \frac{\pi}{6} \right)$$ so the angle between that and the $y$-axis is $\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{3}$